# Fitting the Size of a WPF unto a Windows Forms User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

Using the elementHost method, I've docked a WPF on a Windows Forms User Control. Both have the same size, yet the WPF is not displayed correctly on the User Control (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPERR.jpg)). What am I doing wrong?

WPF Code Snippet:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SlideAnalysis.Views.DesignView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SlideAnalysis.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Height="586"
         Width="431">
```

Comment: Can you post some code? What is wrong with the image you're showing?

Comment: There is not much code to show. It's just that the WPF is not shown in its entirety on the Winforms UC, its somehow cut

Comment: Maybe set your WPF element's `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Comment: I tried, it had no effect.